# bash in-line brace expansion

Tags: bash, readline, brace-expansion

Does bash/readline have a binding or a function that a key combination can be binded to in order to expand in-line braces? 
Similar to the way `M-* key` combination can be used for in-line globbing expansion.

So upon performing a key-combination

`$ {a..z}`

will turn in place into :

`$ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ $(echo {a..z})
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

```
$ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Note that it will expand all the expansions on the command line. No matter where the cursor is placed.
With this command (and `a=this; b=that`):

```
$ echo "$a"; $(echo {a..m}); echo "$b"
```

This will be expanded:

```
$ echo this; a b c d e f g h i j k l m ; echo that
```

From `man bash`:

> shell-expand-line (M-C-e)
>   Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions. See HISTORY EXPANSION below for a description of history expansion.

Comment: Under what circumstances is this supposed to work? I can't reproduce it with `bash` in Emacs command line editing mode in a `tmux` session, for example, or on macOS.

Comment: Make sure that you have the ``` ` ` ``` (or $(...)). Search in man bash for `shell-expand-line (M-C-e)` @Kusalananda

Comment: @Isaac Oh well, maybe the default `bash` on macOS is too old and the most recent `bash` on OpenBSD is wrongly configured or something, or something else (in the desktop environment) is highjacking the keystrokes. Because it ain't working. That's why I was interested in the circumstances under which this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Kusalananda For the keybinding : See what `bind -p | grep shell-expand-line` gives you. For the brace expansion: did you try doing it with two grave accent characters instead of a dollar-and-parentheses? the latter is a recent update to bash, an enter should expand it too. Tell us your `bash --version`

Comment: It did not work for me, but as it turns out you can't do it in vi mode (`set -o vi`). After unsetting vi mode, it worked fine.

Comment: @quasimodo you will need to bind your own key bindings in vi mode